# Can VMware ESXi be installed on a server with 2x480GB DC SSD, Adaptec 8405 SGL, RAID 1?

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, adaptec

```
Intel Xeon E3-1275v5
4x RAM 16384 MB DDR4 ECC
2x SSD SATA 480 GB Datacenter
RAID Controller 4-Port SATA PCI-E - Adaptec 8405 SGL
```

The VMware-VMvisor-Installer-6.7.0.update03-14320388.x86_64 installer image contains the scsi-aacraid driver which should support the Adaptec 8405 SGL.

Unfortunately the VMware vSphere installer doesn't recognize the storage.

[image]

Comment: The card is [on the HCL](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=38507&vcl=true). Have you checked if the firmware version of the card is recent enough?

Comment: And: Is a RAID configured on the card?

Comment: Latest version of the hardware raid controller and RAID is configured, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The card is [on the HCL](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=38507&vcl=true), but requires an async driver (version 6.2.1) which is not included in the vanilla ESXi installation image. You must download it [from here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=DT-ESXI60-ADAPTEC-AACRAID-62158012&productId=491) and create your own custom ESXi image and include that driver.
For creating a customized ESXi image you can use a PowerCLI script like [ESXi-Customizer-PS](https://esxi-customizer-ps.v-front.de/).

Comment: Updates ESXi 6.7 Image Profile-ESXi-6.7.0-20200403001-standard)

Load additional VIBs from Online depots ...
   Add VIB scsi-aacraid 1.1.5.1-9vmw.670.0.0.8169922 [IGNORED, already added]

It says the driver is already added....